# A question on Euler Phi Function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a fixed odd prime. If $n$ is an integer such that $p | \phi(n)$, how much could be said about $n$? Can you think of any relations between $p$ and $n$? Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: $n \geq 2p$ to start, unless $n$ is $p$.

Comment: Either $p$ divides $n$, or $n$ has a prime factor $q$ such that $p$ divides $q-1$.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for Euler's function gives most of the answers:
$$n=p^aq^br^c...$$ $$\phi(n)=p^{a-1}(p-1)q^{b-1}(q-1)r^{c-1}(r-1)=n(1-\frac1 p)(1-\frac1 q)(1-\frac1 r)$$

If p|$\phi(n)$ then we must have:

(a) p must be one of the prime factors of n, and

(b) The index "a" of p in $n=p^aq^br^c...$, must be greater than 1.

Comment: $3$ divides $\phi(14)$; is $3$ a prime factor of $14$?

Answer (score 1):

3 is obviously NOT a factor of 14 but if you look at the formula for $\phi(14)$ the index of each prime factor, 2 and 7, is only 1.  So, condition (b) does not apply.

Comment: However, 3 is a factor of 7-1=6, but I am not sure this is helpful.